How do I get a Plotly Express animated chloropleth map to show multiple countries per year?
I'm running my code on a MacBook Pro, M1, 2020 using a Jupyter Notebook with Python version 3.11.5. I'm using Plotly Express to create an animated chloropleth map that shows which countries were colonized over from 1460 to 1985. Right now, my test data set has 4 countries,--Algeria, Angola, Australia, and Belize --the name of the colonizer for each country--France, Britain, Portugal, Spain, and Not Colonized--and a range of test (dates aren't realistic) years for when each country was colonized. The dataset has 3 columns, "country," "colonizer," and "year" with the above information in each. Here's a subset of the data with 14 years for each country:
| country  | colonizer | year |
| -------- | --------  | ---- | 
| Algeria  | France    | 1844 |              
| Algeria  | France    | 1845 |
| Algeria  | France    | 1846 |
| Algeria  | France    | 1847 |              
| Algeria  | France    | 1848 |
| Algeria  | France    | 1849 |
| Algeria  | France    | 1850 |
| Algeria  | France    | 1851 |
| Algeria  | France    | 1852 |
| Algeria  | France    | 1853 |
| Algeria  | France    | 1854 |
| Algeria  | France    | 1855 |
| Algeria  | France    | 1856 |
| Algeria  | France    | 1857 |
| Algeria  | France    | 1858 |
| Angola   | Portugal  | 1844 |              
| Angola   | Portugal  | 1845 |
| Angola   | Portugal  | 1846 |
| Angola   | Portugal  | 1847 |
| Angola   | Portugal  | 1848 |
| Angola   | Portugal  | 1849 |
| Angola   | Portugal  | 1850 |              
| Angola   | Portugal  | 1851 |
| Angola   | Portugal  | 1852 |
| Angola   | Portugal  | 1853 |
| Angola   | Portugal  | 1854 |
| Angola   | Portugal  | 1855 |
| Belize   | Spain     | 1845 |
| Belize   | Spain     | 1846 |
| Belize   | Spain     | 1847 |
| Belize   | Spain     | 1848 |
| Belize   | Spain     | 1849 |
| Belize   | Spain     | 1850 |
| Belize   | Spain     | 1851 |
| Belize   | Spain     | 1852 |
| Belize   | Spain     | 1853 |
| Belize   | Spain     | 1854 |
| Belize   | Spain     | 1855 |
| Australia| Britain   | 1839 |
| Australia| Britain   | 1840 |
| Australia| Britain   | 1841 |
| Australia| Britain   | 1842 |
| Australia| Britain   | 1843 |
| Australia| Britain   | 1844 |
| Australia| Britain   | 1845 |
| Australia| Britain   | 1846 |
| Australia| Britain   | 1847 |
| Australia| Britain   | 1848 |
| Australia| Britain   | 1849 |
| Australia| Not Colonized | 1850 |
| Australia| Not Colonized | 1851 |
| Australia| Not Colonized | 1852 |
| Australia| Not Colonized | 1853 |

I sorted the dataset by year col_sort_df = colonized_df.sort_values(by = ['Year']) and expected the code to show all 4 countries at the years they overlap, color coded by the colonizer at each year. Instead, the map only shows one colonizer, and one country at a time. Here's the code I used on the sorted dataset:
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# Add a color mapping for each colonizer
colonizer_color = {
    'Britain': 'blue',
    'France': 'red',
    'Spain': 'yellow',
    'Portugal': 'green',
    'Belgium': 'purple',
    'Germany': 'gray',
    'Italy': 'orange',
    'Not Colonized': 'black'
}

# Create the choropleth map
fig = px.choropleth(
    col_sort_df,
    locations="country",  # Column name for countries
    locationmode="country names",
    color="colonizer",  # Column name for the color mapping
    hover_name="country",
    animation_frame="year",  # Column name for the year to animate 
    color_discrete_map=colonizer_color,
    projection="natural earth",  # Projection style for the map
    title="Colonization by England and France (1800s-Present)"
)

# Update layout for a better appearance
fig.update_layout(
    geo=dict(
        showframe=False,
        showcoastlines=False
    )
)

# Show the figure
fig.show()


In this case, I think adding an animation group would solve the problem. If not set, frames will be created with the category variable of the ruling colonial country, resulting in funny animations.
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth(df,
                    locations="country",
                    locationmode="country names",
                    color="colonizer",
                    hover_name="country",
                    animation_frame="year",
                    animation_group='year',# update
                    color_discrete_map=colonizer_color,
                    projection="natural earth",
                    title="Colonization by England and France (1800s-Present)"
                   )

fig.update_layout(
    geo=dict(
        showframe=False,
        showcoastlines=False)
)
fig.update_layout(height=500, width=800)
fig.show()



Thanks so much for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm still having trouble. I want the animation to show multiple countries controlled by multiple different colonizers across time. After adding animation_group = 'year' I'm only getting one colonizer and the countries they colonized at a time. For example, I'll get just Britain for a span of time and only the countries colonized by Britain will appear. Then, it'll jump to another colonizer and only show those countries.

If the requirements are missing from the data posted in the question, please update the data.

Thanks for letting me know. I’ve updated the data to include more categories.

You have updated your data and I have tried to animate with the graph object using the new data. The result was not what you intended, so I did not update the answer. Here is an example of the graph object you referred to. Also, there is a [plotly forum}(https://community.plotly.com/) and I encourage you to post your question there.

Great idea! I’ll definitely post my question in the plotly forum. Thanks for all of your help.
